# Either too little or too many arguments for a nn.Sequential

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, sequential, attention-model

I am new to PyTorch, so please excuse my silly question.

I define a nn.Sequential in init of my Encoder object like this:

```
self.list_of_blocks = [EncoderBlock(n_features, n_heads, n_hidden, dropout) for _ in range(n_blocks)]
self.blocks = nn.Sequential(*self.list_of_blocks)
```

The forward of EncoderBlock looks like this

```
def forward(self, x, mask):
```

In the forward() of my Encoder, I try to do:

```
z0 = self.blocks(z0, mask)
```

I expect the nn.Sequential to pass these two arguments to individual blocks.

However, I get

```
TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

When I try:

```
z0 = self.blocks(z0)
```

I get (understandably):

```
TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but only 1 was given
```

When I do not use nn.Sequential and just execute one EncoderBlock after another, it works:

```
for i in range(self.n_blocks):
     z0 = self.list_of_blocks[i](z0, mask)
```

**Question**: What am I doing wrong and how do I use nn.Sequential correctly in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequential in general does not work with multiple inputs and outputs.

It is an often discussed topic, see  [PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-can-i-pass-multiple-inputs-to-nn-sequential-layers/50868) and GitHub issues [#1908](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19808#) or [#9979](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/9979).

You can define your own version of sequential. Assuming the mask is the same for all your encoder block (e.g., like in the Transformer networks), you can do:

```py
class MaskedSequential(nn.Sequential):
    def forward(self, x, mask):
        for module in self._modules.values():
            x = module(x, mask)
        return inputs
```

Or if your `EncoderBlock`s return tuples, you can use a more general solution suggested in one of the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19808#issuecomment-487291323):

```py
class MySequential(nn.Sequential):
    def forward(self, *inputs):
        for module in self._modules.values():
            if type(inputs) == tuple:
                inputs = module(*inputs)
            else:
                inputs = module(inputs)
        return inputs
```